# How to connect two projects? One for typescript and another is written in bot framework c#

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, botframework

I am using Microsoft bot framework, and I got stuck by one application.

I would like to let the user to ask me for a link redirection first then the bot should prompt up a button to redirect user to the right page without opening a new tab or reloading the whole current page. However, for now it is by default that the link will open another tab and also reload the whole page.
Hence, I am thinking about using a typescript in Angular to get the element of that button and change its onclick event to:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl("/the link I want")
```

However, I really don't know how to invoke this onclick function since the chatbot window will not show up until the user click to open the chatbot and ask the request for a redirect link. Therefore, I must find a way somehow I can let the typescript know that the chatbot is open as well as a redirection movement modification is required.

The only attribute I got from the front end for that chatbot prompt button is its aria-label and className.

Can anyone offer some help or have gone through the same situation?

Comment: HTTP, TCP, Web Sockets, IPC?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616474/ms-bot-framework-pass-the-values-from-server-code-c-to-front-end-code-javas/60616735#60616735) help you?

Comment: Sry Mick, not what I am looking for....I am trying to get a button element created by bot framework in c# backend code to perform an Angular onclick event on the frontend.

Comment: Hi matcheek, I am sorry that this has totally nothing to do with HTTP, TCP, Web Sockets or IPC at all...sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you to achieve this is thru the use of a component dialog on the bot side and filtering on the incoming activity action in Web Chat via the store.

Regarding the component dialog, look over the [13.core-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot) sample in the BotBuilder-Samples repo. If you notice, the `BookingDialog` class (in BookingDialog.cs) extends the `CancelAndHelpDialog`. The `CancelAndHelpDialog` filters the incoming activities looking for specific user-entered values ("help", for example) and acts on it when hit. In your scenario, the user would enter some value that would be caught by your "RedirectDialog" and sent back to the page as an event (or other activity type) when the dialog/logic completes.

Next...

Regarding Web Chat, look over the [04.api/c.incoming-activity-event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/c.incoming-activity-event) sample in the BotFramework-WebChat repo. Here, assuming your bot sent an event (housing the user's value), Web Chat would react when this specific event is received by triggering a page event. You would have an event listener setup to respond to the page event that, when triggered, could open a confirm() or modal or whatever you decide to land on to handle the redirect the user requested.

Hope of help!