# MS Bot Framework pass the values from server code (C# ) to front end code (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, botframework, c#-3.0, direct-line-botframework, azure-qna-maker

I've been using MS bot framework - Chat bot in my project and I'm using QnAMaker in the back end for my chat bot, which is running in direct line bot channel.

On page load using JavaScript front end code, i'm sending some values **say ABC** to the bot (c# code - server hosted) via **createStore** method, after asking the question the bot will start querying it in the qnamaker using **ABC** as strict filters.

After sometime, In one some scenario, i will give input to BOT and change the values as **XYZ**.  up to this everything is fine.

Now, I want to get the values **XYZ** and update that in my front end JavaScript Code.

In other words, i want to reverse the createstore method. or creating a communication from server side to client side

Is there any way to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage the same store in order to receive any activity from the bot (previously named the backchannel approach). For example, you could send an activity from your bot of the `event` type combined with a `name` and a `value`.

**Bot (JavaScript)**

```js
await context.sendActivity({
    type: ActivityTypes.Event,
    name: 'sample:backchannel',
    value: 'XYZ'
});
```

**Bot (C#)**

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
    new Activity { 
        Type = ActivityTypes.Event, 
        Name = "sample:backchannel",
        Value = "XYZ"
    }
);
```

**WebChat**

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
    {},
    ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
            const { activity } = action.payload;

            if (activity.type === 'event' && activity.name === 'sample:backchannel') {
                alert(activity.value); // Do whatever you want in your front-end
            }
        }

        return next(action);
    }
);
```

[View full sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/j.redux-actions) in BotFramework-Webchat documentation

Comment: Hi @Mick , thanks for replying. Now i got some idea on this. It will be great if you provide a working sample bot code - C# code with the implementation of sendactivity. I'm using the dispatch bot template, hence I'm facing some difficulty in inserting the  await context.sendActivity code.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were using C# for your bot code. I have added an C# example, could you give it a try. I couldn't test it yet and C# is not my main language, but it should be fairly similar to the Javascript example.